# How do I build a synthetic measure of economic activity for linear regression?

Tags: regression, history, economic-history, data

I'm trying to estimate the effects of WW2 on the economy using historical data for cities.

The regression is pretty simple:

```
economy1950 = a + b*destruction1945 + c*distance to frontline + d*economy1939
```

The problem is that I don't have good data on economic activity (e.g. GDP) for the cities. 
But I do have data on this:

- the amount of housing built in 1950
- industrial output 1950
- government expenditures 1950

I can plug in any of those measures as "economy1950" but none covers a large range of economic activity.

Now I'm trying to figure out how I could construct a measure/index myself. I'm currently thinking about the following options:

- Rank the three measures and then average them
- Standardize the three measures and then average them
- Multiply the three measures and take the cube root of it

I lose a lot of interpretability using all of those methods. I also don't really know if they are "allowed".

How do I best go about it? Is there another option? Is one of the options clearly better than the others? Should I not do this at all and simply look at the measures separately?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe using principal components analysis?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.
I looked into PCA, and am still not sure how to do it in my case.
It seems to be usually used to choose a subsample of the variables and omit the other ones. 
But I would want to keep most of the variables (ideally, all of them) and combine them into a new one.

Would I use PCA to find the "weights" between the different variables? And the weights would be *Proportion of Variance* PCA assigns to each variable?

Would I still need to standardize the variables or not?

Comment: If you run PCA you can extract the first principal component and use this as the measure/index  in your regression.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for – but maybe it's the best I can get?
Ideally, I'd want a measure that is more informative or more predictive than any single one of the measures/components on their own.